# Wireless headphone modification?

Tags: headphones, wireless

I'm aware that there are a whole slew of products that serve to transmit the audio from an attached microphone (like a lavalier) wirelessly to a receiver unit.

I'm in search of just the opposite: a hip-mounted (or otherwise worn on one's person) device for receiving audio from a wireless transmitter source and sending into some regular attached headphones.

Bluetooth headphones don't cut it because of the latency and compression, and although there are lots of options for non-bluetooth wireless headphones, I'm looking for a device that lets ME choose the headphones and just does the wireless part.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look on stage audio sales sites for 'wireless monitors' - there is a huge range.

The cost may be a little high, but generally the bandwidth on these devices is very good.